# : Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

This is the code I'm trying to execute in **beanshell sampler**:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

String name_lead = vars.get("Name_lead");

String[] lead = name_lead.split("\\s+");
//vars.put("myname",lead[0]);
//vars.put("myname1",lead[1]);
//vars.put("myname2",lead[2]);
for(int i=1; i<=Integer.parseInt(vars.get("title_pass_matchNr")); i++)
{
    String title = vars.get("title_pass_"+i);
    String fname = vars.get("firstname_"+i);
    String lname = vars.get("lastname_"+i);
    String[] fn = fname.split("");
//vars.put("title",title);
//vars.put("fname",fn[1]);
//vars.put("lname",lname);

    if(lead[i-1].equals(title) && lead[i].equals(fn[1]) && lead[i+1].equals(lname))
    {
        vars.put("namep",lead[i]);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> **Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.lang.*; import java.util.*; String name_lead=vars.get("Name_lead");  . . . ''**

I'm not able to understand it. Can sombody help me? How do I fix this?

`name_lead` has something like Mr P singh ..and taking using regex extractor

Comment: Why isn't your code enclosed in a class / methods?

Comment: im doingthis in jmeter beanshell sampler ..i think its not needed

Comment: as i tried to debug there is a mistake in if controller.but im not able to make out

Comment: What does your last sentence in your question mean?

Comment: value for **name_lead** ,im taking from he response  using regex.that value is something like Mr P singh

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a good way to convert this `Error invoking bsh method` error into a more human-readable stacktrace: put your code into a [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

```
try {
    //your code here
}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Error in Beanshell", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

This way you will able to see the exception details in *jmeter.log* file

Another way to add [debug()](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) directive at the very beginning of your Beanshell script. This way you'll get a lot of debugging output into [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29).

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using Beanshell in JMeter tests and scripts development and troubleshooting

Comment: Sure but "Log & Throw" is generally not a good idea. It causes code smell.  Instead, you either log OR throw.   Doing both is redundant.